# Running terragrunt run-all destroy in Jenkins needs user input

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, terraform, jenkins-groovy, terragrunt

I am currently using terragrunt to manage my terraform code, and am running into an error when trying to destroy my infrastructure. I want to be able to spin up development environments (or parts of environments) and delete them easily through Jenkins.

A certain part of my infrastructure is structured so that I need to use the `terragrunt run-all` command, which results in the following user message: `` WARNING: Are you sure you want to run `terragrunt destroy` in each folder of the stack described above? There is no undo! (y/n) ``. Jenkins immediately fails after this output as it expects a y/n input.

For apply I have managed to go around this by saving a plan and then applying it, however for the destroy command I can't find another way. `terraform` commands have an -auto-approve option, but this seems to do nothing to the `terragrunt run-all` command, despite this being in the documentation:

`Using run-all with apply or destroy silently adds the -auto-approve flag to the command line arguments passed to Terraform due to issues with shared stdin making individual approvals impossible.`

Does anyone have any experience of this or any advice? Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else is looking for an answer to this, the flag [--terragrunt-non-interactive](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/cli-options/#terragrunt-non-interactive) can be used.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It throws an error since doesn't get a concrete y or n answer, I think.